# R devtools:document Dependency package not available

Tags: r, devtools

Hi I am following the tutorial [here](http://hilaryparker.com/2014/04/29/writing-an-r-package-from-scratch/) from Hilary and [here](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/description.html) from Hadley Wickham trying to create a dummy package.

However, my package need some external dependencies `XML` and `RCurl` in this case, when I run the command document, it will complain that:

```
> setwd('/home/datafireball/projects/Rprojects/rgetout/rgetout')
> document()
Error: could not find function "document"
> library(devtools)
> document()
Updating rgetout documentation
Loading rgetout
Loading required namespace: XML
Error in (function (dep_name, dep_ver = NA, dep_compare = NA)  : 
  Dependency package XML not available.
>
```

Here is my `DESCRIPTION` file.

```
Package: rgetout
Title: A R package to get all the outlinks for a given URL
Version: 0.1
Authors@R: "Eric Cartman <Eric.Cartman@gmail.com> [aut, cre]"
Description: This package is intended to include as much web extraction functionality as much as     possible. It starts with one function. getout will extract
all the outlinks for a given URL with a user-agent that you can customize.
Depends: R (>= 3.0.2)
Imports:
    XML,
    RCurl
License: MIT
LazyData: true
```

Here is the [source code github repo](https://github.com/biwa7636/rgetout) if you want to get more info.

Comment: I presume that you have installed 'XML' and 'RCurl' on your system....

Comment: @mnel, actually no, I tested the code on my windows box with XML and RCurl installed. Then I copied the code to my ubuntu virtualbox expected it will follow the description and install the packages?

Comment: You need to do a `library(devtools)` or `require(devtools)` before you can call the `document()` function.

Comment: You need to put packages you want "auto-installed" under `Depends:` in the `DESCRIPTION` file, not `Imports:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is assumed that you will have the required tools / dependencies for developing a package when you are 
doing so.

`utils::install.packages` has a dependencies argument that will attempt to install uninstalled packages on which a package depends / (in whichever way they are dependent (suggests/ depends/linkingTo).

`devtools::install_github` will perform similarly.

Installing a package and documenting it as a component of development are quiet different activities
.

Answer (score 6):

If you are having problems with this, even when you have the packages installed and loaded, I suggest you to do the following.

- Delete the `Imports:` and `Suggests:` entries of your `DESCRIPTION` file.
- Make sure you have usethis working by doing `library(usethis)`
- Now start adding the libraries to your `DESCRIPTION` file, by running the following command on your console: `usethis::use_package("dplyr")` for any `Imports:` you need. Repeat this step for every library that is required.

In my case, `dplyr` was the one refusing to load. You can decide where the package will be located by doing: `usethis::use_package("dplyr", "Suggests")`.