# R: devtools::document Error: Dependency package(s) 'dplyr','tidyr' not available

Tags: r

I added a new function to my R package and tried to run document() but received the error:

```
Error: Dependency package(s) 'dplyr','tidyr' not available.
```

I have both packages installed and included in the Imports in DESCRIPTION. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50352057/6557567) suggestion to remove the packages from Imports and run usethis::use_package("dplyr"). When I do so, I see:

```
i The `dplyr` package is required.
x Would you like to install it?

1: Yes
2: No
```

I select 1 and it installs dplyr (which is already installed?) but does not add it to DESCRIPTION.

Similar questions have been posted on stack overflow but most of them do not have solutions or the solutions do not work for me as above.

Comment: Can you confirm `"dplyr" %in% rownames(installed.packages())` returns true? Can you successfully run `library(dplyr)`? Are doing all this in the same R/RStudio session? What OS are you running and what R version are you running? What exactly does your DESCRIPTION file look like?

Comment: You probably have more than one library of packages.  If you install R when running as admin, then install packages as a regular user, they often get installed in different places.  Run `.libPaths()` to see the list of active libraries, and `installed.packages()[,"LibPath"]` to see where each package is installed.

Comment: Yes, `"dplyr" %in% rownames(installed.packages())` returns TRUE and `library(dplyr)` works fine. I am working in RStudio. When I reopened my project this morning `document()` worked without error, so I'm not sure what the issue was! Thanks for the help.